# Sql Server Disk Estimating Tools?

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for a 'calculator' of sorts for planning and estimating Sql Server disk space.  Can anyone recommend something.  I thougth about building an Access database tool for such but thought that this may have been done already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a spreadsheet [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Miscellaneous/estimatingyourspaceneeds/1683/) that may do what you want - stumbled on it a while ago, but haven't actually tried it out.